# GRUB freezes when I reboot with usb mouse connected

Tags: boot, drivers, wireless, grub2, usb

I'm running EFI dual-boot with windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. 
HP Spectre with NVIDIA graphics card.

The problem only happens if I boot up and there is a flash drive or any device connected to the USB port. GRUB freezes and stays there. I have to force reboot the computer and remove the device, only that way it would boot up normally

Comment: Same issue as well. I can use a wired usb mouse during boot but if i boot it up with my logitech G602 wireless mouse, grub freezes and I can't use my keyboard to switch between options. I have to remove my logitech usb reciever and turn my laptop off and on again for it to work. I can plug a usb drive in and boot without grub freezing. I saw lots of posts say upgrade your logitech receiver firmware and enable some sort of legacy usb settings in bios but my bios doesn't appear to have any type of legacy usb settings. Using hp spectre (model 15-DF1033DX) dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu 19.10

Comment: @KBrown I've also had problems with my internal Bluetooth device,  It seems like there may be some problems with the wireless drivers maybe. Apparently HP does not support other operating systems rather than windows thus they don't assure they could be any for Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, I have the same exact problem with my HP Spectre & Logitech Bluetooth mouse. Did anyone one of you by any chance find a solution? if so, would be great if you can share.

Comment: @DoriedAbd-Allah I have not found a solution, This weekend I'll be upgrading to 20.04 with the hopes that it gets fixed, that and also a problem I have with the Bluetooth

Comment: @MarcoCastro thanks for the update. Actually, I upgraded my ubuntu to 20.04 ans till have the problem, however I'm not sure if grub was updated. Wish you good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing further research, I was able to notice that the problem happened with a specific brand of mice. Logi devices(Logitech). I was able to reach out to them and submit a report. Apparently their USB dongle contained some sort of firmware that would trigger some bug in the BIOS at bootup.
They weren't able to fix the issue for me since the bug report error was tedious and I thought moving forward with that process was going to be extensive.

**Solution, I bought a mouse from a different brand. It works perfectly.**

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I tried to disable the USB boot option from BIOS, but it did not work. To solve the problem I used the `efibootmgr` command.

First I ran `sudo efibootmgr` to see the current boot options. Mine was correctly set to start from ubuntu and USB Drive was the last one, so I don't know how the problem was occurring on the first place. Then I `sudo efibootmgr -b <USBbootnum> -A` to make the USB Drive option inactive. This worked for me. After reboot the computer the USB Driver option became active again (don't know why), but the problem went way.

Comment: did not work for me, In fact the usb drive option won't even get inactive

Comment: This did not work for me, after disabling USB drive in both BIOS boot options and with efibootmgr, grub still freezed. Only solution for me was unplugging the Logitech dongle at each startup.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue on an HP Spectre x360 laptop. Grub would freeze if any USB device was connected at startup (Logitech or other). Fixed by updating the BIOS firmware of the laptop.

Comment: I did try, but didn't work for me. I'm glad to hear it worked for you